# Configure eslint to use the default import

Tags: material-ui, eslint

I'm trying to configure eslint for @material-ui with this specific case:
I'd like to import just so: `import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';`
and disable import like: `import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';`

I have configured the `no-restricted-imports` rule to:

```
"no-restricted-imports": [
    "error",
     {
         "patterns": ["@material-ui/core", "!@material-ui/core/*"]
     }
]
```

In my logic it should work like: disable all imports from `@material-ui/core` except `@material-ui/core/*`. What am I doing wrong and how to configure it to my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used path:

```js
{
...
"no-restricted-imports": [
      "error",
      {
        paths: [
          { name: "@material-ui/core", message: "no named import from material ui core" },
          { name: "@material-ui/lab", message: "no named import from material ui lab" },
        ],
      },
    ],
}
```